# Android Sqlite database structure chek in tests

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-testing

I have this test where i dump to logcat my database structure. Problem is that when i recreate database from test it self ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ..."  -> "CREATE TABLE ...") somehow table "sqlite_sequence" is empty.

Same thing done when launching application stetho shows that there is all needed tables in database also table "sqlite_sequence" contains all their names.

How to make my test check work properly?

```
public class DatabaseStructureTest  extends AndroidTestCase {

private static final String TAG = DatabaseStructureTest.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mContext = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_");
    db = DatabaseMarket.getInstance(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
    assertNotNull(mContext);
}


@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    db.close();
    super.tearDown();
}


public void testDatabaseStructure() throws Exception {

    DatabaseMarket.getInstance(mContext).recreateDatabase(db);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_sequence", null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
    cursor.close();
}

}
```

**Update - possible solution**

Instead of "sqlite_sequence" i execute query from "sqlite_master". This returns a bit too much for check egz. "android_metadata" and "sqlite_sequence" but it works in my case.

Comment: use **realm** its a better alternative for mobile database

Comment: Not an option. This isn't a new project. Also it already compiles like forever (2-3 mins). So i don't want to add any more dependencies.